# Does information contained in schema (structured data) need to be visible on webpage?

Tags: schema, structured-data

I want to add "Organization" schema to the home page of my company. There are many properties I want to include into the schema, such as "founder", "contact", "found date", etc. I wonder if I also need to list out these information on my webpage? What penalty will be if I don't?

Google structured data guideline about this part is quite vague: "*Don't mark up content that is not visible to readers of the page. For example, if the JSON-LD markup describes a performer, the HTML body must describe that same performer.*" I'm not sure if this means you can add any schema as long as the content referred to is visible or it means the schema information itself needs to be visible

I tried researching Google structured data guideline, search on google, ask questions in Google Search Community.

Answer (score 1):

Structured data is not a thing in itself, but the data represents the content that is being referenced. Among other things, this means that the data markup MUST match the visible content.E.g., the value for the property `founder` must have an appropriate visible representation in the content. If you believe that this content is not important to users, then you can choose not to show it in the direct download stream using allowed methods, e.g., an accordion or the HTML element `details`.

The lack of correspondence between the SD markup and the visible content is a signal for manual actions by Google such as **[Structured data found on hidden content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175#zippy=%2Cstructured-data-issue)**. Do not do it.